# What is the order of Component.onCompleted in a QML file with many items?

Tags: qt, qml

For example, consider the code below:

```
Rectangle {
    id: idRectParent

    Rectangle {
        id: idRectChild1
        component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Iam Child 1")
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: idRectChild2
        component.onCompleted: {
            console.log("Iam Child 2")
        }
    }

    component.onCompleted : {
        console.log("Iam parent Rect")
    }
}
```

I'm getting the output below if I run it in `qmlscene` (I have tried almost 50 times).

```
Iam parent Rect
Iam Child 2
Iam Child 1
```

Why is the output in the above order, instead of:

```
Iam parent Rect
Iam Child 1
Iam Child 2
```

or

```
Iam Child 1
Iam Child 2
Iam parent Rect
```

or any other combination.

Answer (score 10):

The order is undefined:

> Emitted after the object has been instantiated. This can be used to
> execute script code at startup, once the full QML environment has been
> established.
>
> The corresponding handler is onCompleted. It can be
> declared on any object. The order of running the onCompleted handlers
> is undefined.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal

Comment: If MainPage.qml is loaded by main.qml by property binding - `mainPage: MainPage {}`, will all onCompleted handlers from main.qml be executed before all MainPage.qml handlers, or is it undefined as well?

Answer (score 7):

The order is undefined but it's meaningful (and can be empirically observed) that when `OnCompleted` method is called for one item all of its children are instantiated and safely accessible (and the properties initialized), even if `OnCompleted` event for these children is not called yet.

Comment: This is not true though, as evidenced by the OP when the parent object's `onCompleted` is called even thought he children's are not yet.

Comment: If you don't specify better, what you say would be compatible with what I wrote. My conjecture, observed empirically, is that when the parent launches its `onCompleted` and children didn't yet ,still they are safely **accessible**.

Comment: @Venemo I edited the answer claryfying the concept I wanted to express. Any more feedback on this? You really not observe what I wrote?

Comment: This is much clearer than the previous wording. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The order is dictated by C++ classes and for simple declarations the order remains the same from Qt 4.8 through 5.15.

The example describes a QML component containing items. C++ calls occur in this order:

1. `QQmlComponent::beginCreate()` is called to create the component.
2. `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` is called to create each item in the component.
3. `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` is called recursively for each child declared inside an item.
4. If a child item has no children, it is added to the *componentAttached* stack for later completion.
5. After all children are created via their respective `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` calls, the parent's `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` continues executing and the parent is added to the *componentAttached* stack for later completion.
6. The `QQmlComponent::beginCreate()` call exits.
7. `QQmlComponent::completeCreate()` is called to *complete* the component.
8. The *componentAttached* stack is emptied and `onCompleted` emitted as each item is popped off the stack.

This enforces the following order:

1. `idRectParent` is constructed in `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` and children begin construction via recursive calls to `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` before the function exits for `idRectParent`.
2. `idRectChild1` finishes `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` and is pushed onto the *componentAttached* stack.
3. `idRectChild2` finishes `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` and is pushed onto the *componentAttached* stack.
4. `idRectParent` finishes `QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance()` and is pushed onto the *componentAttached* stack.

`QQmlComponent::completeCreate()` calls `QQmlObjectCreator::finalize()` and the *componentAttached* stack is emptied and `onCompleted` emitted for each item:

1. `idRectParent` is popped of the *componentAttached* stack and emits the `onCompleted` signal.
2. `idRectChild2` is popped of the *componentAttached* stack and emits the `onCompleted` signal.
3. `idRectChild1` is popped of the *componentAttached* stack and emits the `onCompleted` signal.

This order is maintained no matter how deep the heiarchy of items: parent first then children in reverse order of declaration.